# Error when switching from node-sass to sass(dart-sass) on Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript, node-sass, dart-sass

I am using Angular version 10.2.0, NodeJs 14.17.3 and would like to switch from node-sass to package sass (formerly dart-sass). I uninstalled node-sass, deleted node_modules, cleared npm cache, npm install and installed sass. When I run the program, the sass-loader throws me errors.
[image]

Snippet from my package.json:

```
"sass": "^1.43.4",
    "sass-loader": "^10.1.1",
    "simple-line-icons": "^2.4.1",
    "ts-helper": "0.0.1",
    "tslib": "~2.1.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.15.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.1002.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^10.2.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^10.2.4",
```

Can you help me with my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try replacing occurrences of `/deep/` with `::ng-deep` - I think `/deep/` may no longer be supported